# Python parse-html loop won't end

Tags: python, file, parsing, xpath

I have question about loop. My question is how can I write output to file. Problem is my FOR loop won't end. Can you help me with some solution.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib2
import os
import sys
import re
import psycopg2
import time 
import shutil
import logging
import glob
import copy
import urllib
import datetime
import requests
from lxml import html
import requests
import itertools
# Dir BACKUP
global current_backup
# Error log
global error_log
error_log = "rtc_error.log"

global current_time
current_time = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M", time.localtime())

def get_web():
    try:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='{}'.format(error_log))
        try:
            input_sat = open('rtc.xml','w')




            godina  = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")

            mjesec  = datetime.date.today().strftime("%m")



            for x in range (32):
                if x < 32:
                    x = x + 1
                    var = x

                    url = 'http://www.rts.rs/page/tv/sr/broadcast/20/RTS+1.html?month={}&year={}&day={}&type=0'.format(mjesec, godina, var)

                    page = requests.get(url)
                    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
                    a = tree.xpath('//h1/text()')
                    b = tree.xpath('//div[@class="ProgramTime"]/text()')
                    c = tree.xpath('//div[@class="ProgramName"]/text()')
                    d = tree.xpath('//a[@class="recnik"]/text()')


                    for line, line1, line2, line3 in itertools.product(a, b, c, d):
                        clean = line.strip(), line1.strip(), line2.strip(), line3.strip()
                        if clean:
                                print >> input_sat, line+line1+line2+line3
                        else:
                            break


                                #input_sat.write(line.encode('utf-8'))  # the \n adds a line break  

            input_sat.close()
        except:
            logging.exception("Failed to parse web-page! %s"% current_time)
    except:
        logging.exception("Failed to parse web-page! %s"% current_time)
get_web()
```

I don't know where is problem, FOR LOOP or parse with encode characters. Can you give me some solution or better loop.

Ok I changed into this loop:

```
for line in a:
                        clean = line.strip()
                        if clean:
                            print ''                    
                        for line1 in b:
                            clean1 = line1.strip()
                            if clean1:
                                print ''
                            for line2 in c:
                                clean2 = line2.strip()
                                if clean2:
                                    #print line.encode('utf-8'),line1.encode('utf-8'),line2.encode('utf-8')
                                    print >> input_sat, '<item>\n'+'<date>'+line.encode('utf-8')+'</date>\n'+'<start>'+line1.encode('utf-8')+'</start>\n'+'<title>'+line2.encode('utf-8')+'</title>\n'+'</item>\n'
```

But now it's write multplay values.

Comment: why do you need permutations of all xpath queries `itertools.product(a, b, c, d)`. This will increase your recursion dramatically.

Comment: Could you take a minute and reindent you code, please? Also, long lines should be (correctly) wrapped so that horiontal scolling is minimized. Your qustion will be more likely be answered quickly, then.

Comment: Thx guys but i did my code, now it works. Thx for time, if you wanan ill post it.